# Unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

The exact error reads as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Name/Downloads/MachineLearning.py", line 73, in <module>
class d0:
File "C:/Users/Name/Downloads/MachineLearning.py", line 83, in d0
z = hypothesis1(W0,W1,W2,W3,Z0,Z1,Z2,Z3)
File "C:/Users/Name/Downloads/MachineLearning.py", line 41, in hypothesis1
W0 * Z0 + W1 * Z1 + W2 * Z2 + W3 * Z3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

And here is the code that causes the error:

```
x0 = 1
z0 = 1
x1 = int(input("Enter 0 or 1: "))
x2 = int(input("Enter 0 or 1: "))
y = ""
learning_rate = 0.1

w1 = 1
w2 = 1
w3 = 1
w4 = 1
w5 = 1
w6 = 1
w7 = 1
w8 = 1
w9 = 1

v1 = 1
v2 = 1
v3 = 1
v4 = 1

if x1 == 0 and x2 == 0:
    y = 0
elif x1 == 1 and x2 == 0:
    y = 1
elif x1 == 0 and x2 == 1:
    y = 1
elif x1 == 1 and x2 == 1:
    y = 0
else:
    y = 0

def hypothesis(W0,W1,W2,X0,X1,X2):
    W0 * X0 + W1 * X1 + W2 * X2

def hypothesis1(W0,W1,W2,W3,Z0,Z1,Z2,Z3):
    (W0 * Z0) + (W1 * Z1) + (W2 * Z2) + (W3 * Z3)

class z1:
    W0 = w1
    W1 = w4
    W2 = w7
    X0 = x0
    X1 = x1
    X2 = x2   
    z = hypothesis(W0,W1,W2,X0,X1,X2)

class z2:
    W0 = w2
    W1 = w5
    W2 = w8
    X0 = x0
    X1 = x1
    X2 = x2    
    z = hypothesis(W0,W1,W2,X0,X1,X2)

class z3:
    W0 = w3
    W1 = w6
    W2 = w9
    X0 = x0
    X1 = x1
    X2 = x2
    z = hypothesis(W0,W1,W2,X0,X1,X2)

class d0:
    W0 = v1
    W1 = v2
    W2 = v3
    W3 = v4
    Z0 = z0
    Z1 = z1.z
    Z2 = z2.z
    Z3 = z3.z
    z = hypothesis1(W0,W1,W2,W3,Z0,Z1,Z2,Z3)

    print(z1.z)
```

The error seems to be only consistent with the class `d0`, so if you can, can someone please explain why it is happening and how could I fix it? I have tried completely commenting it out, but it still comes back with a error like the one above. When I try to print the other ones though, it comes back `None`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider editing the post to provide a less generic title. This helps people with the same error as you find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of you code! Hint: paste it in, mark it and press the `{}` button. Also make sure your code fits the traceback provided. At the moment they differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions

```
def hypothesis(W0,W1,W2,X0,X1,X2):
    W0 * X0 + W1 * X1 + W2 * X2

def hypothesis1(W0,W1,W2,W3,Z0,Z1,Z2,Z3):
    (W0 * Z0) + (W1 * Z1) + (W2 * Z2) + (W3 * Z3)
```

currently do not return anything explicitly, so they implicitly return `None`. Since you assign this return value to `z` in classes `z1`, `z2` and `z3`, when you later try to access these in class `d0` via `z1.z`, for example, you get a `None` value and your multiplication in `hypothesis1` will raise the error you see.

Instead, you probably mean to return the result of the calculations, i.e.:

```
def hypothesis(W0,W1,W2,X0,X1,X2):
    return W0 * X0 + W1 * X1 + W2 * X2

def hypothesis1(W0,W1,W2,W3,Z0,Z1,Z2,Z3):
    return (W0 * Z0) + (W1 * Z1) + (W2 * Z2) + (W3 * Z3)
```